# Criação de arquivo .CRM e inserção de delimitador (HEXA 0D0A) após determinado bloco de informação

Tags: php

Estou criando um arquivo texto em PHP que salvo com a extensão .CRM, utilizado para arquivos de cobrança de banco. O arquivo, em sua estrutura, possui 3 partes: HEADER, DETALHE e TRAILER. Cada uma possui 400 caracteres exatos no arquivo. Ao final de cada uma dessas partes, preciso, segundo a documentação, inserir:

"No final do arquivo, ou seja, após as informações Header, Detalhe e Trailer deve haver o Tape Mark ou finalizador de arquivos que também é conhecido na codificação como delimitador (HEXA 0D0A). É como se após da última coluna 400 do Trailer fosse dado um ENTER para ir para próxima linha."

Alguém que possa me ajudar a inserir esse delimitador? 
Se abro o arquivo e conto os caracteres, tenho um total de 1202 (400 do header, 400 do detalhe, 400 do trailer e 2 são de quebra de linha entre header-detalhe e detalhe-trailer). Essa quebra de linha preciso eliminar (substituir pelo delimitador) para que o arquivo tenha os 1200 caracteres.

Comment: Sabe o que é `\r\n`? É para isso que servem as tabelas ASCII

Comment: Não põe o `\r\n` no final?